# How set a value from terminal linux?

Tags: python, pytest

I have a problem. I run tests with the help of the question.
In the beginning, the test calls a method that causes me to enter the address of the database (where I am testing). However, I am getting an error:

```
element = "http://" +sys.stdin.readline()../../python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/capture.py:702: in read
raise IOError ("reading from stdin while output is captured")
```

E OSError: reading from stdin while output is captured

below my code.

```
@staticmethod
def setAddress():
    print("Give database:")
    element = "http://"+sys.stdin.readline()
    return element
```

I need to addres add http. How I can change my code? Thanks for help!

Comment: Use an environment variable that is set before you run the tests, then grab its value in the test, in place of the input (`os.getenv("TEST_DATABASE_URL")` instead of `sys.stdin.readline()`.

Comment: No I can't I need set in terminal. :) Thanks for answer.

Comment: @0 0 how I can to this? Because I never make in python environment variable, thanks!

Comment: You can't set it, but you need to set it in the terminal/command line? I don't understand your comment.

Comment: It's a shell environment variable. How are you running the tests in the first place?

Comment: i start test:  pytest -s test.py

Comment: `TEST_DATABASE_URL=some_address  pytest -s test.py`

Comment: thank you It is good solution for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set an environment variable when running tests in your shell:

```
DB_URL=http://xxx pytest
```

and then retrieve it in your tests:

```
import os

…

db_url = os.getenv('DB_URL')
```